# Adding objectbox_generator giving error 1314

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

add objectbox_generator in pubspec.yaml

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  objectbox_generator: any
```

giving this error

```
Cannot create link, path = 'D:\google\flutter\pub\cache\_temp\dirfb7ac440\integration-tests\basics\pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: A required privilege is not held by the client.
, errno = 1314)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows open project in `File Explorer` and click on `File` in the top left corner then click expand more or arrow of `Open Windows Powershell` then select `Open Windows Powershell as administrator` now in that run `flutter pub get`